# where to get facebook login button

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I have implemented facebook authentication for my website with the facebook-omniauth gem.  I am simply looking for a "Login From Facebook" button.  It seems like facebook only advocates using the login button through the XFBML JS, or through an iframe.

I found that facebook does have various images available on their website: 
https://www.facebook.com/images/facebook_logo.gif
https://www.facebook.com/images/fbconnect/login-buttons/connect_light_medium_short.gif

But how can I get access to all of their available images??   (I know I can get a login from facebook image from a 3rd party, but I wanted to get one straight from facebook - just didn't think fb would make it so hard to do without using their javascript libraries or iframes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

here you can generate a button ... not the additional attributes and use them to get different sizes f.e.

sized buttons: small, medium, large, xlarge (default: medium).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The reason I did not want to use that approach, is it seems like the fb-login-button does some extra magic in the background.  When I apply this class to my previous facebook login link, suddenly, the fb login tries to occur in another window (unsuccessfully, still troubleshooting that issue).  Previously, my button correctly redirected the user to login via fb, and then redirected back to my site.  I'm debating on just taking a screenshot and using that fb-login-button as an image, instead of applying the class.

Comment: So I just ended up using the following 3rd party css: http://zocial.smcllns.com/sample.html

Answer (score 1):

Now facebook has their own .png buttons that you can use in your login flow.
Download and follow the instructions
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/checklist/#brandedlogin

Comment: Corrent me if I'm wrong but I don't see a download link on this page, at least not anymore. Is there one or have they changed the documentation after this answer? If it was the move to [facebookbrand.com](https://facebookbrand.com) that changed this, then they neglect to include any kind of "log-in" button or any extensive assets at all, really..